# Why is there a syntax error in the following scala code?

Tags: scala, syntax-error, scala-2.11

```
 def sortAndCountInv[T](vec: Vector[T]): (Int, Vector[T]) = {
  val n = vec.length
  if (n == 1) {
    (0, vec)
  } 
  else {
    val (left, right) = vec.splitAt(n / 2)
    val (leftInversions, sortedLeft) = sortAndCountInv(left)
    val (rightInversions, sortedRight) = sortAndCountInv(right)
    val (splitInversions, sortedArray) = countSplitInvAndMerge(left, right)
    (leftInversions + rightInversions + splitInversions, sortedArray)
   }
 }
```

This code is for counting the number of inversions in a vector,
when I try to compile it Scala IDE for Eclipse gives me the following error: `illegal start of simple expression`, for the line `val (left, right) ...`

Why does this happen?

Comment: Did you try this code/line in REPL? It look likes as IDE bug.

Comment: Yep, it works in REPL. Sorry for not trying there first.

Comment: I prefer IDEA Community Edition. It has nice support for scala.

Answer (score 0):

It's missing a final closing brace. In general "stale" errors will show up in an IDE when code is incorrect; when in doubt it's best to look at just the first error from a command-line compile (maven or similar).

Comment: Nope, I have a closing brace in my code, I just copied it here incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on REPL, this will be an IDE bug. Try IDEA community with Scala plugin. I found it quite nice also still have some problem understanding some complicated structures.